# Oracle data modeler DDL script indentation

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl, oracle-sql-data-modeler

- it's possible modify ddl script rule appearance so i can define before how i want it compose when i select DDL Preview?

for example:

Trigger Source code in origin in the Trigger body tab

that what i obtain when i select DDL Preview for my table:

DDL Script Preview  [image]

on all the syntax i prefer define the rule, like :

- INITRANS TABELASPACE COMPRESS in one row;
- the list of column in primary key definition in the same row;
- trigger shown like in the Trigger body tab;

thanks in advance
Mario

Comment: please add more details, i need to see how your table is defined, and the entire ddl script for it - it's likely something is wrong or confusing our parser, as the default behavior is supposed to be exactly what you're asking for

Comment: here i am i have edited the post and i hope to have improved the exposure